# Play music on background , Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is SIMPLE and good practice to play background music in Rails App.
It's a really simple rails website. It has several static pages.
How do I playing music on background?

thanks!

I am not looking for detailed answer or code.
I just want somebody kindly point me some links, or some keywords I can search.
I googled around and did not find what I want/ Or I didnt realize that was I need.

Comment: Are you sure your audience wants this _feature_? :)

Comment: @summea Yes, As I said, this is a small app for dedicated users. I like to have that feature. thanks for your concern. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the pages on which you want the sound

```
<embed src="path/to/background.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"><embed>
```

Add it to the layout if you want it in all the pages

Answer (score 2):

with HTML 5, you can now use the  tag like this. You can place this on any page that you want your music to play on. (layouts/application.html.erb if you want site-wide)

```
<audio src="public/my_audio_file.mp3" autoplay controls loop>
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio playback</p>
</audio>
```

This link provides further details and options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video